# fixed button goes behind slider in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a fxied button on my HTML site, it takes to another link. I am able to bring it to right place however it gets behind slider of my index page, on rest of pages its fine.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

// hide #back-top first
//$(".back-top").hide();

// fade in #back-top
$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
            $('.back-top').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('.back-top').fadeOut();
        }
    });

    // scroll body to 0px on click
    $('.back-top a').click(function () {
        $('body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 500);
        return false;
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="back-top floatright" style="display: none; z-index:1000;">

<button onClick="window.open('LINK','_blank')">
  <i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true">
    <font size="4">
      Send Enquiry
    </font>
  </i>
</button>
```

I tried using z-index: -1 but didnt work.

If you need any info let me know .
Thanks

Comment: Your style attribute on `p` isn't formatted right. It should be `style="display: none; z-index:1000;"`

Comment: should I replace `<p class` with `<style`?

Comment: just put the `z-index` inside your `style` tag

Comment: rather, put it inside the `style` attribute of the the `p` tag

Comment: Nope, in ideal, you should put all you css for the `p` into his class. In your example it's `.back-top` or assign it a new class and then put you `style` code into this style like so: `.someClass { display: none; z-index: 1000; }`

Answer (score 0):

As per comments, ideally, your CSS would not be inline and would look like this:

```
p.back-top {
  display:none;
  z-index:1000;
}
```